# JSON Jackson parser - how to get position info of a parsed JsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

when parsing a string into a JsonTree, is there a way to get the offset and length of the parsed JsonNodes ?

eg.
final String json = "{"objects" : ["One", "Two", "Three"]}";

is there a way to know the TextNode representing "Two" is starting at position 23 ?

Comment: Why you need to know something like that?
You can always find a string with regex.

Comment: for this simple example it is.  it would be not that easy if you want to know the starting point/length of the ArrayNode representing  ["One", "Two", "Three"]

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to know this? You can find parsers which do expose this information, e.g. https://michel-kraemer.github.io/actson/javadoc/1.2.0/de/undercouch/actson/JsonParser.html

Comment: **DISCLAIMER:** I don't know everything.  That being said - I agree that this information is not useful.  If you are just trying to **retrieve** data, use the **A.P.I.**.  I use this library: [`javax.json.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html).  However, if you are trying to **MODIFY** a `'.json' File`, then you should: ① Parse the **JSON**  ② Update / Modify / Change  ③ Convert **JSON** back `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

FYI, fixed by using the jackson stream api to parse the json message